# Use XML schema groups in XSL transformation

Tags: xslt, xsd

I have group definitions in an XML schema. Like so:

```
<attributeGroup name="my_attributes">
    <attribute ref="ns:foo" />
    <attribute ref="ns:bar" />
</attributeGroup>
```

Also, I have an XML transformation, in which I want to be able to reuse these definitions. Is it possible to create a template that matches such a group? Something like this maybe:

```
<xsl:template matchGroup="my_attributes">
    <foobar>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </foobar>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a template that matches such a group?
>   Something like this maybe:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template matchGroup="my_attributes"> 
>     <foobar> 
>         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/> 
>         <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
>     </foobar> 
> </xsl:template>
> ```

**No, the XSLT `<xsl:template>` instruction doesn't have a `matchGroup` attribute and 
any compliant XSLT processor must raise a syntax error for this reason**.

Something like this is probably close to what you are looking for:

```
<xsl:template match="@ns:foo[../@ns:bar]">
 <!-- Processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

**The meaning of the match pattern above**:

*Match any attribute with* `local-name()` `foo` *that is in the namespace to which the prefix* `"ns:"` *is associated, and whose* "parent" (*the ellement this attribute is attached to)* *has also another attribute that is named* `ns:bar`.

Comment: What exactly does `@ns:foo[../@ns:bar]` mean?

Comment: @Alp: I updated the answer with the explanation that you requested.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but that's not what i intentionally needed. An attributeGroup in XSD means that any of the attributes is allowed, they do not have to occur all at once (disregarding the parent).

Comment: I'll mark your answer as solution since you gave me the insight that my idea is impossible to realize without hardcoding each attribute name (or using namespaces).

Comment: @Alp: You are welcome. As for the misunderstanding, this often happens -- if you are a specialist in one field but ask for help in another, don't expect the experts in the other field to know *anything* in your field of expertise. I wonder what semantics you'd expect from an imaginary attribute `matchGroup`. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: `matchGroup` was a imaginary example for something that matches a `group` or an `attributeGroup` from a schema file which is defined at the root element of the xslt.

Comment: @Alp: XSLT 2.0 has a "schema-aware" profile (usually sold for big money), but I don't remember anything like the "matchGroup" feature you are asking for. @_Michael Kay is the person, who can best answer.